On the meaning and etymology of 有難い
So in Modern Japanese 有難い or more commonly ありがたい means 'thankful', but it is created by combining the 連用形 of ある with がたい, resulting in something that is close in meaning to "difficult to exist/be". Can someone describe the history of the word, more specifically did it always mean 'thankful' and how did it take on that meaning?

No time for a proper full answer, but have a look at the Wiktionary entry for ありがとう.

Thank you very much, if you'd like to draft up an actual (full) answer, I would be overjoyed.

Origins
As described to some extent over at Wiktionary:ありがとう#Etymology, the term 有【あり】難【がた】い is attested all the way back in the Man'yōshú collection of poetry, completed around 759, but with some poems predating that by possibly centuries.  Importantly, the Man'yōshū poems are not Buddhist texts, suggesting that the term was independent of Buddhism.
The construction of the word arigatasi follows regular Japanese word-formation patterns: this is a verb in the 連用形【れんようけい】, the continuative conjugation form used for compounding, plus an adjective: ari ("to be") + -gatai ("difficult"): "hard to be → rare, unusual".  This meaning is how the word arigatasi is used in its earlier attestations.
We see the same structure with the term minikusi ("ugly"), from continuative-conjugation verb stem mi ("to see, to look at") + adjective nikusi ("hateful"), literally meaning "hard to look at", similarly attested in the Man'yōshū.  Even today, we have prosaic terms like yomizurai ("hard to read") or tabenikui ("hard to eat → unpalatable"), created via this same word-formation pattern.
→ There is nothing inherently Buddhist, nor Sanskrit-y, about the formation of the word arigatasi.
Meaning development
Arigatasi originally meant just what we would expect from its constituent parts ari ("to be") and katasi ("hard, difficult"): "hard to be, unlikely to exist, hard to come by: rare, unusual".  Over time, this "rare" sense took on favorable overtones, leading to the modern sense of "welcome, nice to have".  Consider the example included in the Wiktionary entry:

この天【てん】気【き】はありがたいね。 ― Kono tenki wa arigatai ne. ― This weather sure is welcome (lit. This weather sure is hard to come by).

And from there, the shift to usage in expressions of gratitude, noted here as attested since at least 1423, is relatively straightforward.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If you'd like to expand & clafify your answer by more directly refuting the folk etymology that connects ありがたし with the 盲亀浮木 simile, you can see how that simile is deployed in the canonical Chinese translations of a number of Buddhist texts by searching for 盲亀 at https://21dzk.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp/SAT2018/master30.php . I do not see any occurrences of 難有 in these passages; instead, we find such things as 難得, 難値, & 難聞, in phrases that use the simile to emphasize how rare and difficult it is to obtain human form, or to meet with a Buddha or hear the Buddha-Dharma. (E.g., 人身難得如優曇花。我今已得。如來難値過優曇花。我今已値。)

According of one theory, the origin of 有難い is from an allegory in the Buddhist Scriptures, 盲亀浮木のたとえ. Buddha said in the allegory that it is very difficult to be born as a human and that it hardly happens. In Buddhism, it is joyful to be born as a human.
The Buddhist Scriptures are written in Sanskrit, which is an ancient Indian language. They were tranalated in an ancient Chinese language, and then they were translated in Japanese language. A part of the allegrory is translated like 「ところが、阿難よ。 私たちが人間に生まれることは、 その亀が、丸太棒の穴に首を入れることが有るよりも、 難しいことなんだ。 有難いことなんだよ」.
I think that the word 難有 or 有難(it may be a word in an ancient chinese language that means "difficult to exist") came out in the process of Sanskrit translating to an ancient Chinese language, or It may be only the concept of 有難い is from Buddhism but the word itself may be created in Japan.
Anyway, it is difficult to judge whether it is right or not because the Buddhist Scriptures were written in an ancient Chinease language about 2000 years ago and we can hardly see them.
Also, it hardly happens that others do something good for you. so, they are thankful things. 有難い became a word that shows thanks in this logic.
Source: https://1kara.tulip-k.jp/buddhism/2016111050.html
https://slowlifehack.online/wealth-of-wisdom/literature/1973/

Was the original Buddhist text written in Japanese? If originally written in another language, what is the original phrase?

The Buddhist Scriptures are written in Sanskrit, which is an ancient Indian language. They were tranalated in ancient Chinese language, and then they were translated in Japanese language. I don't know how they are written in Sanskrit.

Thank you very much for your answer, this is very interesting! Considering things had to be translated to Japanese, would you say the term 有難い already existed, or was it created for the translation itself?

An allegory  in the Buddhist Scriptures, 盲亀浮木のたとえ, is source of 有難い. A part of the allegrory is translated like 「ところが、阿難よ。 私たちが人間に生まれることは、 その亀が、丸太棒の穴に首を入れることが有るよりも、 難しいことなんだ。 有難いことなんだよ」. Surely, the word 有難い didn''t exist in ancient Indian language. It was created in the process of translating.

Do you know when the Japanese translation got published?

I don't know, but intellectual people in Japan at that time read the Buddhist Scriptures in an ancient chinese language(漢文), so if they are not translated in Japanese, intellectual people could understand them.

As a side note, 難有 is not treated as a lexical unit in any Chinese dictionaries I currently have access to.  Also, 難 in Chinese seems to have more negative overtones than just "difficult", as we see even in Japanese compounds like 避難 where the 難 isn't just "difficulty" but more like "disaster". So as Chinese, 難有 parses out more as "unpleasant to have". Consider also Chinese 難看 ("unpleasant to look at → ugly"). Granted, this is using modern references. I cannot yet find the source text for the 涅槃経 to confirm.

It is difficult for us to know an ancient Chinese language and to see the Buddhist Scriptures written in them because they were written about 1500 years ago. Many Buddhist says that 有難い is from  the Buddhist Scriptures. It is difficult to judge whether it is right or not. It may be only the concept of 有難い is from  Buddhism but the word itself may be created in Japan.
